# PowerShell hide errors messages on console instead output to error.txt

Tags: powershell, scripting

Within CMD I'm calling a PowerShell script as seen below:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File "CALL %0\..\source\profiles\favorites.ps1"
```

When `favorites.ps1` runs I suppress all errors using `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"`

The script does a whole bunch of `Copy-item`, `Get-ACL` and `Set-acl` stuff. Due to the nature of the script there are a lot of errors, which I hide from the console using `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"`. How can I continue to hide all errors on console but output them instead to `.\error.txt` ?

Comment: You could possibly redirect standard error by adding `2>.\path\to\errorlog.txt`

Comment: Yes that could work but that wont redirect anything if      $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" is enabled. I need a solution that hides errors on console and redirects all errors as well to error.txt

Comment: I only did a really quick test, but omitting the `ErrorPreference` and specifying the redirection didn't print the errors to the screen but did redirect them to the file

Comment: `$ErrorActionPreference` should be set to `Continue`. this way, it will tell powershell to display each errors, without interrupting the script (this is the default behaviour). However, errors won't be displayed since you are redirecting them to your file, using `2>> path\to\erros.txt`

Comment: @arco444 you were right, I cant believe I didnt try that from the get go. Thank you.

Comment: Another option is to dump the contents of $error to a file at the end of the script.

Comment: @KeithHill Does $error populate even if ErrorAction is set to SilentlyContinue?

Comment: Yes it does. That's essentially the error audit log.  :-)  But using $error has other issues.  It is a global so you should either clear the log at the top of your script or not the current size and then at the end use that info to dump only the errors from your script.  Also there is a max size on the $error collection determined by `$MaximumErrorCount` which defaults to 256 on V4.